# PowerShell, regex, Replace things that are not

Tags: powershell, regex-negation

Using PowerShell I want to replace everything in a line in the file myFile.txt that is quoted in parenthesis that is not ("Sally") with ("Admin").  Is this the right way to do so, or is there a more appropriate way?

```
(Get-Content .\myFile.txt) -replace '\(\"(?!Sally).*\"\)', '("Admin")' | Set-Content .\myFile.txt
```

The contents of myFile.txt is:

```
("Bob")
("Sally")
("Tom")
```

And I'd like it to be:

```
("Admin")
("Sally")
("Admin")
```

Comment: As a minor thing, maybe use a negated character class instead of the `.*` You don't have to escape the double quotes and if `Sallys` would be valid you can include the double quote in the negative lookahead `\("(?!Sally")[^"]*"\)`